# Which statistical test to use to test if ERH or BRH is true?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test

My graduate student Dom is interested in finding evidence for either the “enemy release hypothesis” (ERH) or the “biotic resistance hypothesis” (BRH). If ERH is true, we would expect more parasites on the native species, whereas if BRH is true, we would expect more parasites on the exotic species. Dom measures a native (Vieja) and exotic (Tilapia) congeneric species in Panama, and tests for differences in number of parasite species (richness) on individuals of each species.  He collects 8 fish of each species in each of 5 locations, and does a full dissection of all organs (e.g., muscles, liver, stomach, intestine, etc.). These are the only two congeneric species in Panama, and therefore, the only species that he is interested in. Further, these are all the areas where these two fish species are found to co-occur in Panama. What test should Dom use to test his hypothesis?

I'm guessing two-sample t test because there are two data samples, unpaired, to test... but I'm not sure.